# Proving $C([0,1])$ is complete

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

> Prove that $C[0,1]$ with the sup norm $||f|| = \sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} f(x)$ is complete.

Here is my attempt.

> Let $(x_n)$ be Cauchy in $C[0,1]$. So there exists $N$ so that for $m,n > N$, we have
> $$||x_m - x_n|| = \sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |(x_m - x_n)(x)| < \epsilon.$$
> For any element $t \in [0,1]$, we have
> $$|(x_m - x_n)(t)| \leq \sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |(x_m - x_n)(x)|.$$
> So for $m,n > N$, we have
> $$|(x_m - x_n)(t)| \leq \sup\limits_{x \in [0,1]} |(x_m - x_n)(t)| < \epsilon.$$
> So $(x_n(t))$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers, so it converges to some real number, $a$, so $(x_n (t))$ converges to some function $x(t)$. Furthermore, this converges is uniform since there exists an $N$, independent of $x \in [0,1]$, so that for $||x_m - x_n|| < \epsilon$ for $m,n > N$. It suffices to show that the limiting function $x(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: You are not done yet. You proved that $x_n(t)$ is a Cauchy sequence for each $t$, and hence convergent. But why should the pointwise limit of $x_n(t)$ be the same as the limit of $x_n$ in $C[0, 1]$? (Oh, and you switched your notation from $s_n$ to $x_n$.)

Comment: Actually you proved that your sequence of functions is *uniformly* Cauchy. What does that mean in terms of convergence for your sequence? Can you see what you have to so now?

Comment: Surely you don't think the proof is over. You have not even written down the limiting function!

Comment: You've shown that the sequence of functions $\{x_n\}_n$ converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. Then what can be said about the limit function?

Comment: I edited the first post with an updated attempt. I think the outline of the proof is proving that $(x_n (t))$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$, which gives a limiting function $x(t)$, then argue that $x(t)$ is continuous. I can't figure out how to finish, however, because all I know is that $x_n (t)$ converges to a real number: how do I know it converges to a function evaluated at $t$, and how do I know that the convergence is uniform?